I believe the graph in this textbook relating emitter current and base-emitter voltage for a BJT is incorrect. Am I mistaken?
Look at this image relating emitter current and base-emitter voltage for a BJT from Bolyestad.

I believe this in incorrect based off this equation for emitter current from Sedra Smith:

From this equation, given a set of constant Vcb values, the emitter current should most notable vary towards the origin (Vbe towards 0) because here the Vbe term is small so the Vcb term can dominate.  But when the Vbe term is large as Vbe is near 0.7v, the turn on voltage, the first term dominates and the Vcb term becomes insignificant.  Therefore, the plot should instead look like:

Clearly this isn't to scale and the axis values/units are meaningless, but you get the exponential nature I am trying to show here.
I think this makes sense not only from the Sedra Smith equation but also just thinking of the semiconductor physics: as Vbe is significantly large enough to forward bias the base emitter junction, then Vbe should completely determine (approximately) the emitter current assuming the BJT is in the linear region (this implies Vbe is large enough such that Vcb is reverse biasing the base collector junction.)  Therefore the exponential curves converge when Vbe is large.  However, for small values of Vbe, the base emitter junction is largely shut down so the base collector junction can dominate the emitter current profile.
Clearly I must be missing something or mistaken somewhere but I am having a hard time seeing it.  What do you all think?

Tried a circuit with 2N2222. I get the Sedra figure (not so spaced, quasi paralleled).

Note that if Vbe is >0, Vbc is <0 ...

For every transistor I tried, I get the Boylestad figure. Ie curves do not converge for large Vbe voltages but spread out exactly as shown. Only for small Vbe values your second figure (Sedra) with parallel lines on top of each other applies, but you have to really zoom in to see that.
